# tr -d or sed -e 's/\r//g' can't remove CRLF from file in MINGW32

Tags: text, sed, mingw32, tr, file-processing

i have this CERTIFICATE file
[image]

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIFIDCCAwgCAQAwIDEeMBwGA1UEAwwVdmF1bHQudmF1bHQtcGVyc28uc3ZjMIIC
IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA2h1Io+IPgBFYa+L9TFQ3hXDk
dKJFHVBHFx6RaYMDHJe75c/Ozq3zwAwlDlPviTvB96OyuBX9KIBDk5b0QCELYHym
omCSm1GO+Izxgu26aBvrbgycwUml+lXqW8R6reMpEBnaIRgOvPhIsncaR3iQBt8m
yPo/v5ouPCrVGJ5Hehi4ll0vwxI5/ETlJIjnDqBODwWRLvktv4ysHRj/4hyh5Yn0
IalOn9Cxo0w2zVQhFE63n3enz7c=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

i try to remove all the  CRLF from the file

like this also tried tr -d "\n"   and tr -d "\r" :

```
cat <<EOF >${TMPDIR}/csr.yaml
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
 name: ${CSR_NAME}
spec:
 groups:
 — system:authenticated
 request: $(cat ${TMPDIR}/server.csr | base64 | sed -e 's/\r//g')
 usages:
 — digital signature
 — key encipherment
 — server auth
EOF
```

no matter what i do
the end result file the part of the CERTIFICATE content is still contains the line break
How can i remove it ?
[image]

Comment: Did you try `tr -d '\r'` ?

Comment: yes i did still the text with line break

Comment: If you remove `LF` it's just going to be one long line.... Anyway, use `base64 -w0` to output with no newilnes. `is still contains the line break How can i remove it ?` with `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Try cat -v file.csr | tr "^M" "\n" | tr -d "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat -v file.csr | tr "^M" "\n" | tr -d "\n"
```

This will output the file with Windows file endings (-v) before using tr to replace the file endings (^M) with a new line and then delete the new lines (-d)

Comment: If the solution works. Please take the time to up vote and accept the answer.